# Combining PHP code run on server with ready-made HTML email template

Tags: php, html, email

I was wondering how can I possibly combine on my FTP server the PHP sourcecode that meant to send emails while launched on server side with an e-mail template which I have already made using some email generator.

The main problem I've got is that I can't find any answer on how to setup these files on server and combine them with eachother, should I use one file or several named differently. I'm sorry that I represent such novice level, so excuse me for my ignorance.

Here's my PHP sourcecode that is meant to be a base for an e-mail sending, I just don't know how can I possibly combine it with my HTML email template.

```
<?php
$receiver = "receiver@gmail.com"; 
$subject = "Subject example"; 
$message = "Message example"; 
$sender = "sender@gmail.com"; 
$header = "From: " . $from;    

mail($receiver, $subject, $message, $header);
echo "ok!"; 
?>
```

Is there any way I can simply include the sourcecode of my emails HTML template to this code ?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood the problem, you can easily write php and html in a common file. Open and close the php, html tags as and when needed.

```
<?php
$receiver = "receiver@gmail.com"; 
$subject = "Subject example"; 
$message = "Message example"; 
$sender = "sender@gmail.com"; 
$header = "From: " . $from;


mail($receiver, $subject, $message, $header);
echo "ok!"; 
?>
<html>
    <body>
       <p>Write HTML here</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to include your HTML in the $message variable, one way to do it is like this:

```
<?php
$receiver = "receiver@gmail.com"; 
$subject = "Subject example"; 
$message = "<div>Your email HTML Template here</div>"; 
$sender = "sender@gmail.com"; 
$header = "From: " . $from;

mail($receiver, $subject, $message, $header);
echo "ok!"; 
?>
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work, my sourcecode of HTML template starts with '<head> <xml> [...]', and once the script is run on server I get the message 'Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in /home/stevestifler/public_html/script.php on line 6' . The 6th line starts with the <head> <xml>. Got any solutions for this error ?

Comment: You need to make sure to all your single or double quotes.That's why you have a parse error
Ex: 
`$message = "<div class="example">hello</div>" //This won't work`
`$message = "<div class=\"example\">hello</div>" //This will work`